# Frequent PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed errors with RDS and rails / activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm seeing a large number of `PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed`errors in a rails 4 application using unicorn. The DB pool is set to 10, the connect_timeout is 2, the reaping_frequency is 10, and reconnect is true.

None of this seems to completely eliminate the problem. It is MUCH more frequent right after a deploy when the unicorn servers are restarted.

There do not seem to be actual connection issues to the database - many many connections are working just fine.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the problem turned out to be the octopus gem. We couldn't find a fix beyond removing the gem entirely.

The fix proposed here did not work for us:

https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/319

Comment: What are you using instead of octopus?